# Why does visual studio code mark a line with a red underline as if it was an error if it is not?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

Why does visual studio code mark a line with a red underline as if it was an error if it is not?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5w5em.png)

Comment: If you hover over the red underlines under the `DOCTYPE` and `html` tags, what does it say?

Comment: In the Problems tab, what does it say about the errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see at the bottom right corner of the editor(right next to the smiley) you have selected CSS. Whereas your file is an html. Just click on 'CSS' button and select html. The errors should disappear.